# matching query does not exist Error in Django (OneToOneField)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Please help me I don't know what I am doing wrong I am getting an error
**Available_time matching query does not exist.**
I use here OneToOneField from the Available_time database from Sunday to Saturday. I don't understand why this error is showing.

```
class Available_time(models.Model):
    timezone = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='IST_time')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nickname)

class RMDatabase(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    country= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    countryCode = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    motherTongue = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    secondSpokenLang = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    secondSpokenLangReason = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    interstedIn = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    skillLevel = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    qualificationAwardedBy = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    qualificationFile= models.FileField(upload_to='folder/')
    videolink = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    preferredDayTime = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    sunday= models.ManyToManyField(Available_time,blank=True, related_name='sunday')
    monday =  models.ManyToManyField(Available_time, blank=True,related_name='monday')
    tuesday= models.ManyToManyField(Available_time,blank=True, related_name='tuesday')
    wednesday =  models.ManyToManyField(Available_time, blank=True,related_name='wednesday')
    thrusday= models.ManyToManyField(Available_time,blank=True, related_name='thrusday')
    friday =  models.ManyToManyField(Available_time, blank=True,related_name='friday')
    saturday = models.ManyToManyField(Available_time,blank=True, related_name='saturday')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.motherTongue
```

**My view.py

here I simple takin input from the user and save the database. the problem I facing from **if request.POST.get('sunday-evening'): to till end if conditions. if remove those lines then working fine.

```
def MNFRM(request):

x= RMDatabase()

# if request.user.is_active:
#     if x.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).exists():
#         return render(request, 'relationshipmanager/userexists.html')

if request.method == 'POST':
    x.user_id = request.user
    x.country = country_list[str(request.POST.get('country')).upper()]
    x.province = request.POST.get('state')
    x.city = request.POST.get('city')
    x.contact = request.POST.get('number')
    x.countryCode = request.POST.get('code')
    for it in ["motherTounge", "nativLanguage", "mediumOfInstruction", "qualifiedInParticularLanguage"]:
        if request.POST.get(it):
            s = it+','
            x.secondSpokenLangReason += s
    x.motherTongue = request.POST.get('motherTongue')
    x.secondSpokenLang=request.POST.get('secondSpokenLang')
    for it in ["Script Writing", "Producing Films", "Directing", "Acting", "Editing", "Animation"]:
        if request.POST.get(it):
            s = it+','
            x.interstedIn += s
    x.skillLevel=request.POST['SkillLevel']
    x.qualification=request.POST.get('qualification')
    x.qualificationAwardedBy=request.POST.get('qualificationAwardedBy')
    x.qualificationFile=request.FILES['qualificationFile']
    x.videolink=request.POST.get('videolink')
    x.save()
    

    
    if request.POST.get('sunday-evening'):
        x.sunday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('sunday-afternoon'):
        x.sunday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('sunday-morning'):
        x.sunday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))
    if request.POST.get('monday-evening'):
        x.monday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('monday-afternoon'):
        x.monday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('monday-morning'):
        x.monday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))
    if request.POST.get('tuesday-evening'):
        x.tuesday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('tuesday-afternoon'):
        x.tuesday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('tuesday-morning'):
        x.tuesday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))
    if request.POST.get('wednesday-evening'):
        x.wednesday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('wednesday-afternoon'):
        x.wednesday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('wednesday-morning'):
        x.wednesday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))
    if request.POST.get('thrusday-evening'):
        x.thrusday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('thrusday-afternoon'):
        x.thrusday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('thrusday-morning'):
        x.thrusday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))
    if request.POST.get('friday-evening'):
        x.friday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('friday-afternoon'):
        x.friday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('friday-morning'):
        x.friday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))
    if request.POST.get('saturday-evening'):
        x.saturday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='evening-time'))
    if request.POST.get('saturday-afternoon'):
        x.saturday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='afternoon-time'))
    if request.POST.get('saturday-morning'):
        x.saturday.add(Available_time.objects.get(nickname='morning-time'))

    x.save()
    # email_message = EmailMessage(
    #     "RM Registration Successful",
    #     "Hi "+str(request.user.first_name)+' '+str(request.user.last_name) +
    #     ",\nYou have successfully registered for our Relationship Manager programme.",
    #     settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    #     [request.user.email]
    # )
    # email_message.send()
    subject= "Relationship Manager form is successfully submitted "+ "."
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to = request.user.email
    
    html_content = render_to_string('relationshipmanager/email.html')  # render with dynamic value
    # Strip the html tag. So people can see the pure text at least.
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
    # create the email, and attach the HTML version as well.
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    return redirect('base')
    
    # return HttpResponse('Thanks your application has successfully registered, we will notify you via email about your application status.')
    # z = xyz()
    # print(z)
    # return render(request, 'lpp/lppreg.html', {})

return render(request,'relationshipmanager/rmreg.html',{})
```

Comment: It seems that in your database there are no `Available_time` instances with `nickname` equal to `'afternoon-time'`, `'evening-time'` or `'morning-time'`. For this code to work there should be at least three instances of  `Available_time` in your database with  `'afternoon-time'`, `'evening-time'` and `'morning-time'` as values for `nickname` respectively.

Comment: please, sir, give me one example

Comment: For that I would need to see the objects in your DB. What you can try is `Available_time.objects.filter(nickname='afternoon-time').count()`. With that you will get the number of `Available_time` instances that have `'afternoon-time'` as `nickname`. You can do the same with `Available_time.objects.filter(nickname='evening-time').count()` and `Available_time.objects.filter(nickname='morning-time').count()`. In the three cases you should be getting a number greater than 0. Otherwise you'll have to  create `Available_time` objects with the corresponding `nickname` values